# How to change expiry time in cookie settings for fancybox ?

Tags: jquery, cookies, fancybox, jquery-cookie

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
  if(check_cookie == null){
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 30 * 60 * 1000 });
    $("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
  }   
});
```

It works. I want change to expires time to 3 days. How can I fix it?

Comment: is this a simple maths question?

Comment: What version that you use? from the wiki page, it's just need to specify like this: $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 3 }); for 3 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you can pass a date

```
var date = new Date();
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie("the_cookie", "the_value", { expires: date });
```

or send the days as parameters

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 3 });
```

**Output**

if you run the function in browser console where jquery cookie is already present as source, in both the cases it prints

"the_cookie=the_value; expires=Mon, 30 Dec 2013 08:28:36 GMT"

(current time is Mon, 27 Dec 2013 08:28:36 GMT)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var check_cookie = $.cookie('the_cookie');
  if(check_cookie == null){
    $.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: time()+3600*24*3 });
    $("#hidden_link").fancybox().trigger('click');
  }   
});
```